# I'm trying to render an animation, but the pixels are messed up

Tags: rendering, animation, cycles-render-engine, objects, camera

What happened to the carpet? Why is the render messing up the pixels and stuff? Someone, please tell me how to fix this. I'm using Cycles render.

[image: rendered image]

Comment: looks like a lot of noise.  Are you using Cycles?  then you might need to use a denoiser.

Comment: Hello and welcome. Instead of having users go through links and external sites please use the builtin tools to embed images in your post. See [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [GIFs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963)

Comment: Try to increase the Sampling > Render > Max Samples

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming you are using Blender 3.0 and above, well they are using a new way to render in cycles and intersecting geometry will have this issue like the carpet so what you can do is select the carpet and move it up by a very small amount like 0.001 m or even smaller.

[image]

And also cycles renders with interiors are known to be very very noisy so to deal with that, You can use the denoiser if it is a still image you need but if its a animation you may have to increase the Amount of samples until the noise is barely noticeable.

Comment: Ty!! this worked

Comment: @hii np but if you could, you can mark this as the answer...

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to enable Denoising. Go to Render Properties/Viewport and enable Denoising. Then go to Render Properties/Render and enable Denoising also. I hope this is helpful.